# Bit field initialization in C++20 with `|| new int` construction

Tags: c++, c++20, bit-fields

I came across the page about C++20 bit field initialization https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field#Cpp20_Default_member_initializers_for_bit_fields , where for C++20 the following example present (simplified here):

```
struct S {
    int z : 1 || new int { 0 };
};
```

The page does not explain the construction `|| new int`.  Is there any dynamic allocation here `new int`? What is the default value of `z`, is it `{0}`? Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to parse this declaration:

- `int z : (1 || new int) { 0 };`
- `int z : (1 || new int { 0 });`

where everything inside `()` is interpreted as the size specifier.  Since "the longest sequence of tokens that forms a valid size is chosen" as indicated by cppreference, the second alternative is assumed.  Therefore, by [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (the second operand to the `||` operator is not evaluated if the first operand is `true`), the declaration is equivalent to

```cpp
int z : 1;
```

with no default value for the bit field.

---

The rule governing this ambiguity resolution can be found in [[class.mem]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem#9):

> In a *member-declarator* for a bit-field, the *constant-expression* is
> parsed as the longest sequence of tokens that could syntactically form
> a *constant-expression*.

Syntactically, a [*constant-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#nt:constant-expression) is defined as follows:

> *constant-expression*:
> 　　*conditional-expression*

Thus, a top-level assignment operator is not accepted, but `?:` is okay.  Compare two examples from the linked cppreference page:

```cpp
int x1 : 8 = 42;                 // OK; "= 42" is brace-or-equal-initializer
int y1 : true ? 8 : a = 42;      // OK; brace-or-equal-initializer is absent
```

which, subject to the aforementioned specification, are parsed respectively as:

```cpp
int x1 : (8) = 42;
int y1 : (true ? 8 : a = 42);
```

where `()` again denotes the expression that is parsed as the size specifier.